# How to implement this query in spring query custom mongoDB using mongotemplate

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, mongotemplate

```
db.getCollection('gift').aggregate([
     { $match: {nick_name: { $ne: '' }} },
     { $project : {_id: 0, nick_name : 1, price: { $toLong: "$price" }, unit: { $toLong: 1000 }, use: { $toLong: 1 }} },
     { $project : {nick_name : 1, price: { $multiply: ["$price", "$unit"] }, use: 1} },
     { $group: {_id: '$nick_name', price: { $sum: '$price' }, total: { $sum: '$use' }} } ]);
```

This is my code

```
 public List<GiftCodeAggregate> statistic() {
        Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("nick_name").ne("");
        MatchOperation matchOperation = Aggregation.match(criteria);

        //ProjectionOperation projectStage = Aggregation.project("nickname", "price");

        //ProjectionOperation projectPrice = Aggregation.project("price").and(ConvertOperators.ToLong.toLong("price")).as("price");
        //ProjectionOperation projectUnit = Aggregation.project("unit").and(ConvertOperators.ToLong.toLong(1000)).as("unit");        ProjectionOperation projectUse = Aggregation.project("use").and(ConvertOperators.ToLong.toLong(1)).as("use");        //ProjectionOperation projectNickname = Aggregation.project("nick_name", "price", "use").andInclude("nick_name");
        //ProjectionOperation projectTotal = Aggregation
                .project( "price", "use").and("use").multiply((Number) Fields.field("price")).as("total");

        //ProjectionOperation projectTest = Aggregation.project("price")
                .and(ConvertOperators.ToLong.toLong("price")).as("price");

        //GroupOperation groupOperation = Aggregation
                .group("nickname")
                .sum("price").as("price")
                .sum("total").as("use");

        //List<AggregationOperation> aggregationOperationList = Arrays.asList(matchOperation, projectStage, projectPrice, projectUnit, projectUse, projectNickname, projectTotal);
        List<AggregationOperation> aggregationOperationList = Arrays.asList(matchOperation, projectTest);
        TypedAggregation<GiftCodeEntity> aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(GiftCodeEntity.class, aggregationOperationList);
        AggregationResults<GiftCodeAggregate> result = this.mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, GiftCodeAggregate.class);
        return result.getMappedResults();
}
```

I'm having a problem/error when convert field price from to string to calculate , it looks like my code is going wrong?

Comment: Records sample: 

    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("543253"),
        "ticket" : "9JDD567",
        "price" : "10",
        "quantity" : 5,
        "count_use" : 1,
        "nick_name" : "nickname",
        "create_time" : "2020-11-08 20:29:54"
    }

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
public List<GiftCodeAggregate> statistic() {
    MatchOperation match         = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("nick_name").ne(""));

    ProjectionOperation project1 = Aggregation.project("nickname")
        .and(ConvertOperators.ToLong.toLong("price")).as("price")
        .and(ConvertOperators.ToLong.toLong(1000)).as("unit")
        .and(ConvertOperators.ToLong.toLong(1)).as("use");     

    ProjectionOperation project2 = Aggregation.project("nickname", "use")        
        .and(ArithmeticOperators.Multiply.valueOf("price").multiplyBy("unit")).as("price");

    GroupOperation group         = Aggregation.group("nickname")
        .sum("price").as("price")
        .sum("use").as("total");

    Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(match, project1, project2, group);

    return mongoTemplate
        .aggregate(aggregation, GiftCodeEntity.class, GiftCodeAggregate.class)
        .getMappedResults();
}
```

Reduced version:

```
MatchOperation match         = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("nick_name").ne(""));

ProjectionOperation project  = Aggregation.project("nickname")
    .and(ArithmeticOperators.Multiply.valueOf("price").multiplyBy(1000)).as("price")
    .and(ConvertOperators.ToLong.toLong(1)).as("use");

GroupOperation group         = Aggregation.group("nickname")
    .sum("price").as("price")
    .sum("use").as("total");

Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(match, project, group);
```